# How do you manually open an expandable?

Tags: materialize

I want to trigger the opening and closing of a [collapsible](http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) from javascript. Does anyone know how, or else does anyone know about a more complete documentation than [materializecss.com](http://materializecss.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tip:

- Go here: http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html
- Open your Dev tool panel (Tab: Console)
- Paste this:

  ```
  $('#introduction > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div.collapsible-header').click();
  ```
- And hit Enter

Just to say that you only need to trigger **click** on the `.collapsible-header` class to achieve this.

Comment: I was hoping to achieve this without simulating a click, but what works, works.

Comment: This just toggles the collapsible. I want to just open it. I suppose I could search the classes that are added to the <li>, buuuuuut...